# R grep whole words separated by special characters

Tags: r, regex

Suppose there is a vector of sequences of the form `"foo"` or `"foo|baz|bar"` (one single word or multiple words separated by special character like `"|"`), and we are also given a word and we want to find to which items of the vector it has a **whole word** match.

For example the word `"foo"` has a whole match in `"foo|baz|bar"`, but not a whole match in either `"foobaz|bar"` or `"bazfoo"`.

First I tried to use `"\\b"` that indicates either the start or the end edges of a whole word and it works successfully:

```
grep("\\bfoo\\b", "foo")         # match
grep("\\bfoo\\b", "foobaz|bar")  # mismatch    
grep("\\bfoo\\b", "bazfoo")      # mismatch
```

Then I tried to add `"|"` as the other possible separator of both ends, and group it with `"\\b"` using `[` and `]`:

```
grep("[|\\b]foo[|\\b]", "foo|baz|bar")  # mismatch!
grep("[|\\b]foo[|\\b]", "foo")          # mismatch!
```

Later I found `\\b` is not indicator of *start* or *end* of the character string, but start or end of a whole word (so many characters like space and `,|-^.` but **not** numbers and underline `_` separate whole words). So `"[|\\b]foo[|\\b]"` matches to all of these strings: `"foo", "foo|bar|baz", "foo-bar", "baz foo|bar"` but not to `"foo_bar"` or `"foo2"`.

But my question still remains: Why `"[|\\b]foo[|\\b]"` pattern fails to match with `"foo"`?

Comment: So hard to me to select the correct answer as most of them are really perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\b matches at the following positions

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character. (Word characters are a-zA-Z1-9_)

Since | stands for alternation operator in regex, you will have to escape it.

So the regex `\bfoo\b` would match `foo` in `foo|bar` because | is a non word character. There is no need to use the character set `[\b\|]`

Edit: As flodel pointed out below \b inside the character set represents the backspace character. So it would match the | inside [\b\|] and not word boundary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strplit`:

```
> "foo" %in% unlist(strsplit("foo|baz|bar", split = "|", fixed = TRUE))
[1] TRUE
```

Which you can vectorize:

```
> z <- c("foo|baz|bar", "foobaz|bar", "bazfoo")
> x <- c("foo", "foot")
> sapply(strsplit(z, split = "|", fixed = TRUE), function(x,y)y %in% x, x)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am more specially interested to know why grep("[|\\b]foo[|\\b]", "foo") mismatches?

Comment: Because you need to escape `|`. For the same reason, I chose to use `fixed = TRUE` inside `strsplit`.

Comment: If I am looking **only** for the "|" as the separator, "\\b" is not a good choice, so your answer seems better for this case

Comment: It is also programmatically friendly: as you can see, no ugly pasting required to create a regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks flodel. Your answer is perfect. I wish it was possible to select 3 answers correct for this question - I even tried!

Answer (score 1):

Since `|` has special meaning in a regular expression, you need to escape it, i.e. use `\\|`:

```
ptn <- "\\bfoo[\\|\\b]"

grep(ptn, "foo|baz|bar") 
[1] 1

grep(ptn, "foo")          
integer(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great comment. I found even "\\bfoo\\b" works for my aim. Do you think refinement of your answer is needed?

Comment: @AliSharifi If you want to refine my answer, please go ahead.  I believe I have answered your question as posted.

Comment: Here is something interesting: `grep("afooa", "afooa")` gives a match. So does `grep("[a]foo[a]", "afooa")`. So does `grep("\\bfoo\\b", "foo")`, but not `grep("[\\b]foo[\\b]", "foo")`. Any idea?

Comment: I found the answer to my question here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html. *Inside a character class, \b is a backspace character.*. So this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
gregexpr("foo|", "foo|baz|bar", fixed = TRUE)[[c(1, 1)]] > 0
gregexpr("foo|", "foobaz|bar", fixed = TRUE)[[c(1, 1)]] > 0    
gregexpr("foo|", "bazfoo", fixed = TRUE)[[c(1, 1)]] > 0
```

This approach is different in that you can utilize spacing options that you supply `gregexpr` to find words consisting of two words:

```
gregexpr("foo|", "baz foo|", fixed = TRUE)[[c(1, 1)]] > 0 
gregexpr("  foo|", "baz foo|", fixed = TRUE)[[c(1, 1)]] > 0
```